# show/hide a div if radio selection is true

Tags: apex, class, jquery, code

I want to show all contents inside a div if a user selects a radio button (true). If false to hide it.  By default I have  styled one of the div to display:none.   Its partially working. My trouble is only the question inside the div im hiding is being displayed if  I select "true" but I need the radio buttons to display also. I don't know why its not  being displayed.  Below is what I have working so far.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <div>Are you an existing customer?</div>
  <fieldset>
    <apex:selectradio id="radios" value="" >
      <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
      <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
   </apex:selectradio>
 </fieldset>
```

```
 <div class="form-group" id="seekBorrow" style="display: none;"> 
    <div>Is the amount you are seeking to borrow, plus any? </div>
        <fieldset>
            <apex:selectradio>
                <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
                <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
           </apex:selectradio>
       </fieldset>
  </div>        

  $j("input:radio[name$=radios]").change(function () {
        var radio_value= $j(this).val();
        if(radio_value =='true'){
            $j('#seekBorrow').show();
        } else {
            $j("#seekBorrow").hide();
        }
    });
```

markup after rendered in browser:

```
     <div class="form-group" id="seekBorrow" style="display: block; > 
        <div>Is the amount you are seeking to borrow, plus any current?</div>
           <fieldset >
           </fieldset>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you show what your markup looks like after it is rendered in the browser?

Comment: this is what I get after its rendered <div class="form-group" id="seekBorrow" style="display: block; > 
    <div>Is the amount you are seeking to borrow, plus any current?</div>
 <fieldset >
 </fieldset>
</div>

Comment: I have tried with a new page with your code exactly. But I am having no issue with rendering the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be an answer to this question. I really find no issue according to your description. Here is my code for the page and controller and the result.

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="TestExchangeController">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <apex:form>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div>Are you an existing customer?</div>
        <fieldset>
            <apex:selectradio id="radios" value="{!radioValue}" >
                <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
                <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
            </apex:selectradio>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" id="seekBorrow" style="display: none;"> 
            <div>Is the amount you are seeking to borrow, plus any? </div>
            <fieldset>
                <apex:selectradio>
                <apex:selectoption itemvalue="true" itemlabel="Yes" />
                    <apex:selectoption itemvalue="false" itemlabel="No" />
                </apex:selectradio>
            </fieldset>
        </div> 
    </div>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        $("input:radio[name$=radios]").change(function () {
        var radio_value= $(this).val();
        if(radio_value =='true'){
            $('#seekBorrow').show();
        } else {
            $("#seekBorrow").hide();
        }
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestExchangeController {
    public String radioValue {get; set;}
    public TestExchangeController() {
    }
}
```

**Result**
[image]

So from my understanding. Your issue is not in what you have described in your question. I can't tell what it is for now as I can't think of any. But just let you know by following your code I am not getting any issue.

Comment: Yea that is exactly what I want it to do.  Its a really strange issue not sure why its doing that. Thank you though

Comment: @nerdyperson you can simply paste my code and try in a new test page. I think it will also work for you. If it is, go adding elements from your current page into your current page until it stops working. Then you know what is breaking your page

Comment: Ive tried it. but this one particular div it doesnt work but else where it does work.

Comment: @nerdyperson Have you tried to create a test page with my code and see whether it works?

Comment: yes i did and it worked on the test page

Comment: @nerdyperson Then you can trying adding parts of your code in your current page into the test page piece by piece. And you will find a certain point that it stopped working. The last part you added is where the problem lies

Comment: Thanks! Found the issue. It had to do with my value on the selectradio.